# EMD in Python vs. Matlab

Tags: matlab, python, empirical-mode-decomposition

I want to move an analysis pipeline from Matlab to Python. I'm noticing a slight difference between the IMFs generated by the `emd` function in Matlab and those created by the `emd.sift.sift` function for Python. Specifically, I'm calling:

```
imf = emd(signal,'SiftRelativeTolerance',0.1,'MaxNumIMF',4) #matlab
imf = emd.sift.sift(signal, sift_thresh=0.1, max_imfs=4) #python
```

And obtain the following IMFs:
[image]

Comparing the two functions, I can't really figure out what may be driving the difference. Does anyone know what may be causing this (and how to fix it)?

**Links:**

[Matlab emd](https://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/emd.html)

[Python emd](https://emd.readthedocs.io/en/stable/stubs/emd.sift.sift.html#emd.sift.sift)